# UICollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath effects multiple cells - swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

- Swift, no storyboard, UICollectionView from xib file

I am running very simple code to update cell's background color but, more then one cells are updating.

```
        override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // getting images from library
    images = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Image, options: nil)

    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    var nipName2 = UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle:nil)
    collectionView.registerNib(nipName2, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell")
    var nipName = UINib(nibName: "MyViewCell", bundle:nil)
    collectionView.registerNib(nipName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
 }

 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
 }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
 }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyViewCell
    cell.frame.size.width = 60
    return cell
 }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView{
    switch kind
    {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        return headerView
    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
 }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
 {
    var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
 }
```

I have about 300 different cells. I want to update just third one but randomly many other cells' background changing.

Comment: I'd suggest to override `setSelected:animated:` of your `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Are you allowing multiple selection in the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: - "collectionView.multipleTouchEnabled = false" is not working if this is what you mean.
-"collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false" is not working also.

Comment: Not I mean `allowsMultipleSelection`

Comment: The problem is with reusing cells, just make sure that you reset the background for all other cell that you do not want to be selected. 
Use this method to enable the background for the selected one and disable for all others
    func cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: @fatihyildizhan Can you share more of your code please?

Comment: Whole codes are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So collection and table views have a strong concept of view reuse. This allows for large performance gains since it does not have to keep [in your case] 300 cells in memory at the same time.

When you are setting the background color on some cells, those cells have the potential to be reused when scrolling. Since you are not explicitly setting the background upon the view showing, it just uses whatever it currently is.

To fix this just set the color when the view is requested:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
   // This does not guarantee to be a fresh, new cell, can be reused
   var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyViewCell
   cell.frame.size.width = 60
   // Explicitly set the background color:
   cell.backgroundColor = .whiteColor() // or whatever your default color is
   return cell
}
```

Now it is obvious this will cause additional side-effects. Say you change the background color of a cell to red and scroll away. When you come back you are now setting it back to white. That being said, you need to track which cells (probably by storing their indexes) are selected and set their color appropriately.